# Does Animal Crossing: Let's Go To The City let you play NES games?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

I've been wondering if *[Animal Crossing: Let's Go To The City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_City_Folk)* (entitled *Animal Crossing: City Folk* in North America) for the Wii contains some NES games like the N64 and GameCube *Animal Crossing* games did?

If so, I cannot seem to find them. How do you get them?

Comment: This game is also known as Animal Crossing: City Folk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Nintendo Power magazine, they did NOT include old NES games in the Wii version of Animal Crossing.

Comment: Thnx, then at least I can shop searching

Comment: To follow up, this seems to be the reason they're not available: "All NES games [originally in Animal Crossing] are downloadable via Virtual Console, for Wii by 500 points. This is why unlocking NES games was removed in Animal Crossing: City Folk."

Comment: That makes sense :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, according to the [Animal Crossing Wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com):

> - All NES games (Except for Clu Clu Land D and Golf) are downloadable via Virtual Console, for Wii by 500 points. This is why unlocking NES games was removed in Animal Crossing: City Folk.

But your question contains a bit of misinformation:

> - Some NES games were rereleased in Classic NES Series for GBA. Like Advance Play, the games are slightly streched but two players is available. This is why unlocking NES games was removed in Animal Crossing: Wild World.

The NES games seem to be limited to the GameCube and N64 [versions](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Crossing_%28series%29) of the game.